# How to trigger a lambda via cloud watch events/event bridge in localstack using awslocal

Tags: .net, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-event-bridge, localstack

I am struggling to find any information on how to setup triggers/rules on a lambda so it will trigger with certain event bridge events via the cli as almost all examples on aws are via http requests to set it up.

In this scenario I am using localstack on docker to spin up everything locally for developers systems so ideally I am trying to work out what syntax I need to provide the `awslocal` cli (basically a wrapper around aws cli).

Here is what I have so far which seems to create the lambda and but I cant find out what command I need to run to setup the rule to direct certain events to the lambda.

```
# Setup IAM stuffs
awslocal iam create-role --role-name lambda-dotnet-ex --assume-role-policy-document '{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [{ "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": {"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"}, "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"}]}'
awslocal iam attach-role-policy --role-name lambda-dotnet-ex --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

# Setup handler for each event type
awslocal lambda create-function --function-name some-event-handler --zip-file fileb:///Dist/SomeEventHandlingLambda.0.0.0.zip --role arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/lambda-dotnet-ex
```

Then inside the lambda there is a doetnet (C#) handler sig like so:

```
[LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]
public async Task ProcessEvent(CloudWatchEvent<string> message, ILambdaContext context)
```

Currently I'm fine to just route ALL events to this lambda, but struggling to find docs/examples around this, so any help would be great.